# Programmatically read SP 2007 contents and write in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, 2007, migration

Can I read the SP 2007 custom lists, document libraries and write in SP 2013. Please help with some samples or links.

Comment: Do you want to migrate the information or what is the task?

Comment: Yes,I want to migrate the site from SP 2007 to SP 2013 programmatically.

Comment: I think it would be cheaper and quicker for you to use a migration tool like Quest, Metalogix etc, they have trial versions and other pricing plans for larger amounts of data

Comment: To migrate content from SP2007 to SP2013 you should pass by SP2010, my this tool couls help you http://spmigration.codeplex.com/

Comment: Is there any command help to use them with SPMigration?